# Imacos Error-1100: Wrong format Eval Statement

Tags: javascript, eval, imacros

What is wrong with this Imacros Eval Statement:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL(var s1 = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(\"herf=\")+6); s2.substring(0,s2.indexOf(\"\"\"))")
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s1 = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(\"herf=\")+6); s2.substring(0,s2.indexOf(\"\"))")
```